# Deriving an identity with rotation generators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, group-theory

I am trying to justify the following identity on page 68 of [Osborn's notes on group theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ho/GNotes.pdf):

$$e^{-i\pi J_{3}}J_{2}e^{i\pi J_{3}} = -J_{2}.$$ Here, the $J_{i}$ are the typical angular momentum operators. We do not have the explicit form of $J_{3}$ or $J_{2}$ - just the commutation relations:

$$[J_{i}, J_{j}] = i \epsilon_{ijk}J_{k}.$$

I tried writing the LHS as:

$$[e^{-i\pi J_{3}}, J_{2}]e^{i\pi J_{3}} + J_{2}$$

and showing the first term to be equal to $-2J_{2}$ but this isn't working out. How do I show the given identity?

Comment: You need the identity $e^{A}Be^{-A}=B+[A,B]+\frac{1}{2}[A,[A,B]]+\ldots $ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#) with $A=-i\theta J_2$ and $B=J_3$.  The identity is valid for any $\theta$ so once you have developed $e^{-i\theta J_2}J_2 e^{i\theta J_2}$ and recomposed the resulting series you can set $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero This BCH formula is introduced much later in the text.

Comment: it’s a pretty generic identity, not limited in applications to formal group theory.  Think $e^{itH/\hbar}\hat A e^{-itH/\hbar}$ in quantum mechanics….  anyways: granted it should not come “much later” but maybe the author has reasons for delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, 3 ways, at least.

1. Geometrically: two right angle rotation of $\hat y$ around the z-axis. Behold.
2. Convince yourself this is a ***Lie algebra identity***, so it should hold for *all* nontrivial representations, including the doublet (Pauli matrices), which you can easily compute explicitly, since you know the full expression for the exponential of Paulis. But the result should hold for all representations, then. Do this.
3. The series for the basic [Hadamard lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) is all but trivial,
   $$e^{-i\pi J_{3}}J_{2}e^{i\pi J_{3}} =  J_{2} -i\pi [J_3,J_2] - {\pi^2 \over 2!} [J_3,[J_3,J_2 ] ] + i {\pi^3 \over 3!}[J_3, [J_3,[J_3,J_2 ]]] ...  \\
   =\left (J_2 -{\pi^2\over 2!} J_2 + ...\right ) -\pi J_1 + {\pi^3\over 3!} J_1 - ...
   $$
   is easy to sum: do it, recognizing the cosine and sine series.